# evil-mode error when try :reg

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

Please see the figure for the problem. What's is more interesting, is that I copied the two packages directly from git repository of spacemacs, inside which :reg works just well.

Appreciate it if there's any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: I like the symbols you chose for "diminished" modes. Would you mind sharing it?

Comment: Yes, actually most of them come from spacemacs


(lch-diminish auto-complete-mode " Ⓐ" " A")

(lch-diminish whitespace-mode " Ⓦ" " W")

(lch-diminish paredit-mode " Ⓟ" " P")

(lch-diminish flyspell-mode " Ⓢ" " S")

(lch-diminish yas-minor-mode " Ⓨ" " Y")

(lch-diminish auto-fill-function " Ⓕ" " F")